# React Toastify is broken while showing. How can I show react toastify correctly in the top of the page?

Tags: reactjs, react-toastify

Hi i am trying to show react toastify but it is not showing correctly. It's broken while showing.

Here is my code.
import React from 'react';
import { toast, ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';

```
const Toast = () => {
    const showToast = () => {
        toast('Hi there! I am react toastify.');
    }
  return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={showToast} className="btn btn-danger mt-5 d-block mx-auto">Click Here</button>
        <ToastContainer/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Toast;
```

And it is output
[Here is the output](https://i.ibb.co/1dJrNwS/toast.png)

If I click on the button it's showing broken toast and it's not moving from the screen.
How can I solve this problem please help me.
Thanks in advance. <3

Answer (score 4):

Are you importing the css as well? I think it's

```
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.min.css';
```